Camera app tries to write videos to removed SD card. How to set path to internal SD card?
Sony Xperia z3c, Lineage OS 18 (Android 11).
I used to have an SD card in my phone and the camera app would write there (I think it did, pretty sure).
I had to remove the SD card permanently (broken SD card reader).
Now, when I launch the camera app, I can take normal and panoramic pictures, but when I switch to movie, I get a "can't access SD card" message (translation mine). At this point, the message remains even if I switch back to still picture, until I shut off and relaunch the app.
How come?
Is there a way to set a path for the videos?

If there's one it's in the app settings. Check it before the message appears.

@ChanganAuto There's a hamburger menu top left but it's only about pictures settings (flash/quality/delay/...). I can't find any other settings menu. And in the generic settings menu -> application -> camera I can wipe the cache and set permissions, but there are no app-specific settings. Is there another menu I'm missing?

Did you set the SD card as an adaptable storage?

@AndrewT. It's possible that I did back then. I can't remember for sure. I remember there were "two filesystems" (internal and external SD) that were similar, though I'm not sure all apps would use the external. That kinda bugged me but I lived with it. Before removing the card, I moved the content to internal SD naively/manually. If I did set te card as adaptable, is there a way back? Note that the reader is not completely broken, I just need to hold the card in place as it won't lock. I can do that for the time of a copy operation.
